# Fail2ban for nginx post flood ignores time intervals

Tags: debian, nginx, fail2ban

I'm trying to create a fail2ban filter that is going to ban the host when it sends over 100 POST requests over 30 seconds interval.

jail.local:

```
[nginx-postflood]

enabled = false
filter = nginx-postflood
action = myaction
logpath = /var/log/nginx/access.log
findtime = 30
bantime = 100
maxretry = 100
```

nginx-postflood.conf

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST>.*"POST.*
ignoreregex =
```

Using GREP i was able to test the regular expressions and indeed it matches Host and POST requests.

Problem is that it bans **any Host that performs at least one POST request**. This means likely that it's not taking *findttime* or *maxretry* options into consideration. In my opinion it's timestamp issue.

Sample line of nginx log:

```
5.5.5.5 - user [05/Aug/2014:00:00:09 +0200] "POST /auth HTTP/1.1" 200 6714 "http://referer.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
```

Any help?